# Limiting buddy press features based on membership level (PMPro)

Tags: plugins, php, buddypress, community

I'm building a website for a client, I'm pretty new to Wordpress and PHP. I've been using buddypress and Paid Memberships Pro to build a community.

So the requirement is that one member type must not be able to send friendship requests, private and public messages to others unless they pay a fee, but can receive friend requests, private and public messages from other members.

I've tried using PMPro's Buddypress add-on to limit the features, but it only completely disables a feature for a member type.

I'm really confused about how I should go about implementing this. Any help is much appreciated. :')

Answer (score 0):

Our docs are here:
https://www.paidmembershipspro.com/add-ons/buddypress-integration/

When you edit a membership level, for the "unlock BuddyPress" settings, choose the "Yes - Give members access to specific features" option and it will show checkboxes for each BuddyPress module.

This should work. Make sure the general settings for non-members are locking down everything.